# How to send floats via UDP packets larger than 1500 bytes locally and parsing them

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, udp, buffer

I am trying to send a very large array of floats through UDP. I am working with floating point and not quite sure how to parse these back to their original state at the server. The server and client will be running locally between two applications. Whereas the server will be converted to a C# application.

Client:

```
var PORT = 33333;
var HOST = '127.0.0.1';

var dgram = require('dgram');
_data =[-28.5686,97.3002,142.458,0.440512,2.45745,-0.144664,-0.17135,-18.0888,-0.507999,1.4921e-021,3.27051e-018,-0.0534133,-0.000146994,33.8001,0.463196,4.90246e-021,5.86576e-018,-0.0957984,2.09062,-14.5077,0.266143,-4.29059e-007,-1.04696e-007,-7.84019e-016,-4.04058,-15.1361,-3.75471,6.63063e-020,2.15707e-017,-0.352291,7.47538e-005,29.8537,5.90907,3.48822e-023,-4.28574e-019,0.00699938,1.40942,-15.474,0.186975,0.0293333,-0.019122,4.3858e-005,0.01778,-0.263464,0.123309,-0.196127,0.018499,0.0899181,-0.193886,0.0187146,0.0906704,-0.193708,0.0189286,0.0912595,-12.7908,0,-7.41445,-51.7233,9.71027,-4.09645,-0,1.34465,0,42.7628,43.1268,-53.5281,-0,0.542484,0,-15.8093,1.1398,-8.18984,-11.3353,5.42235,10.9137,-30.5178,-1.01592,1.72285,-26.2457,0,0,-0,0,0,-29.8264,-0.995051,0.607773,-112.753,0,0,-53.037,0,0,-0,0,0,-33.1392,-1.09366,5.26616,-111.292,0,0,-50.936,0,0,-0,0,0,-32.1005,-1.06312,0.623497,-103.333,0,0,-43.6037,0,0,-0,0,0,-5.9451,-0.207234,4.09042,-96.4444,0,0,-38.244,0,0,-0,0,0,19.4098,9.98358e-016,10.5068,50.3766,4.8873,2.22908,3.1563e-016,2.57567,-7.09555e-018,-36.3347,40.6501,48.4687,-7.43586e-006,0.592876,-2.70893e-006,16.9705,-0.244893,-1.64202,11.331,5.42212,-10.9131,29.2193,-0.97661,-1.74543,24.8369,0,0,0,0,-0,29.7912,-0.993986,-0.605762,112.622,0,0,52.9584,0,0,0,0,-0,33.0111,-1.08992,-3.26718,111.073,0,0,51.0729,0,0,0,0,-0,32.4514,-1.07348,1.33472,102.94,0,0,43.1189,0,0,0,0,-0,5.87599,-0.204834,-2.10028,96.0519,0,0,38.4021,0,0,0,0,-0,-2.97445,-2.05615,0.876116,5.61002,-7.05385,-0.893018];

var client = dgram.createSocket('udp4');
const buf = new Buffer(_data);

  client.send(buf, 0, buf.length, PORT, HOST, function(err, bytes) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('UDP message sent to ' + HOST +':'+ PORT);
    client.close();
});
```

Server:

```
var PORT = 33333;
var HOST = '127.0.0.1';

var dgram = require('dgram');
var server = dgram.createSocket('udp4');

server.on('listening', function () {
    var address = server.address();
    console.log('UDP Server listening on ' + address.address + ":" + address.port);
});

server.on('message', function (message, remote) {
    console.log(message.length);

});

server.bind(PORT, HOST);
```

Comment: I think this should work, just use `new Buffer(JSON.stringify(_data))`, although not sure if you are going to run into max size problems, maybe it'd be best if you send it in chunks.

Comment: I am actually able to send the entire chunk as a string. I wonder how this is possible. As the size is 1510b, and i understand IPv4 UDP should not exceed 500b.

Comment: I'm only getting 1486 bytes here although if you add IP headers and stuff you could get that. I don't know why it complains about it's length though, right now you are merely constructing a `UInt8Array` of 200 something elements, it's striping everything but the lowest byte (mind you it first appears to be cast to an Integer).

Comment: @JavaCake IPv4's generally accepted UDP payload limit is 534 bytes or thereabouts, to avoid fragmentation. You can send more, up to 65507 bytes, but fragmentation increases the risk that it won't arrive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here's a way to pack floats into `Buffer` with `TypedArray`s:

```
var ta = new Float32Array(_data);
var buffer = new Buffer(ta.buffer);
```

`TypedArray`s are a new addition to Javascript so your node version might not support them. Here's another way to get them into the `Buffer`:

```
var buffer = new Buffer(_data.length * 4);
_data.forEach(function(float, index){
    buffer.writeFloatLE(float, index*4);
});
```

Now it's up to you to read them on the server. From NodeJS server you can read them like this:

```
server.on('message', function (message, remote) {
    console.log(message.length);
    var arr = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < message.length; i+=4){
        arr.push(message.readFloatLE(i));
    }
    //arr = your array of floats.
});
```

Regarding your question with UDP max size, it will depend on your network's MTU and of course the data type you use. `Doubles` are 8 bytes, `Floats` are 4 bytes and `Strings` depend on the encoding you use. I did a test on your `_data` with `Floats` and it gets me 864 bytes, with `Doubles` the data grows twice as much and with strings, it got me close enough to `Doubles` (but data depends on the length of the number).

I think you only have two options if you don't want to be sending more than allowed. You either send it on chunks or compress it.

To compress it you can use `zlib` with the resulting `buffer`:

```
var zlib = require('zlib');
zlib.deflate(buf, function(err, buf){ //deflate, gzip, etc
    client.send(buf, 0, buf.length, PORT, HOST, function(err, bytes) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('UDP message sent to ' + HOST +':'+ PORT);
        client.close();
    });
});
```

And then decompress it on the server:

```
var zlib = require('zlib');
server.on('message', function (message, remote) {
    console.log(message.length);
    zlib.inflate(message, function(err, message){
        var arr = [];
        for(var i = 0; i < message.length; i+=4){
            arr.push(message.readFloatLE(i));
        }
        console.log(JSON.stringify(arr));
    });
});
```

It got me 1/4 reduced with `Floats` and `Deflate/Inflate` (so around 600 bytes). I'd play around with other compression/decompression methods although remember there's a performance price here.

If you want to send it on chunks, you can estimate the size of the payload. For example, if you only want to send 500 bytes then you can only send (500 -28)/4 elements (118). So you'd splice the array and send that first, then splice it again for 118 elements until you are left with 0 elements.

Check out the [**Docs**](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html) for Buffer methods on other number types (Int32, Floats, Doubles, BE, LE, etc).